# How do I convert an array from the ViewBag to a JScript array using Razor Syntax?

Tags: javascript, c#, arrays, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to re-code the following razor syntax to be workable code and am stuck:

```
    var ServiceIndex = @ViewBag.ServiceID ;
    var ServiceName = @ViewBag.ServiceName ;
    var ServiceNotes = @ViewBag.ServiceNotes ;
```

My problem is that right now the ViewBag for those 3 arrays is empty and so it pukes on the lone semicolon.

Comment: The other Question does not deal with `JsonConvert.SerializeObject`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to translate it into JSON on a server-side.

```
<script>
    var ServiceNotes = @(Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ViewBag.ServiceNotes)));
    var ServiceName = @(Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ViewBag.ServiceName)));
    var ServiceIndex = @(Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ViewBag.ServiceIndex)));
</script>
```

Then access it directly in JS.

The empty array is correctly processed by JsonConvert, so, if it is empty you will get something like

```
var ServiceNotes = [];
```

For the convenience of debugging and avoiding nested function calls you can also split serializing and output.

```
@{
   string serviceNotesJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ViewBag.ServiceNotes);
   string serviceNameJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ViewBag.ServiceName);
   string serviceIndexJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ViewBag.ServiceIndex);
}

@section scripts 
{
    <script>
        var ServiceNotes = @(Html.Raw(serviceNotesJson));  
        var ServiceName = @(Html.Raw(serviceNameJson));
        var ServiceIndex = @(Html.Raw(serviceIndexJson));
    </script>
}
```